# Problems with the Enterframe Event

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have been developing a game using Flex, and used the Timer class to keep the main loop going.

However, when I tried using the enterFrame event to do the main loop, there were a few problems.

First of all, physics simulation seemed way too fast. Is the enterFrame event called more than once per frame? I set the application's global frame rate to 24, so shouldn't the application set off the event every 1/24 of a second?

And the second problem is that when the game runs like this, some MXML components that are added are not shown. I have absolutely no idea why this happens.

Help me please?!?

Thanks.

Comment: Some frames take longer to render than others. Setting the FPS to 24 means that a new frame will be rendered *roughly* 24 times per second, but not exactly. The enter-frame event is broadcast only once per frame, however it's possible that you've attached the same event listener to it multiple times (resulting in that function being called multiple times per frame). What was your timer interval? Also, we can't help with the missing components unless we see some code (the part where they're added would be a good start)

Comment: Are you using Box2D for your physics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't count on the framerate to be even, or that the enterframe is called at a fixed interval. Even the timer-class isn't 100% accurate.

When doing timings, always use the delta between frame-updates and use that delta for your calculations. Also be sure to put in a safe-guard that the delta never exceeds some value to avoid strange behavior when the flash application freezes up for some unexpected reason.

This article explains it all perfectly:
http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Answer (score 1):

The framerate is a desired value. If a user runs it on a slow machine, you might experience their output to be too slow. How about reverting to the good old 
[setInterval](http://192.150.14.120/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary646.html)?

Comment: +1, you're right about the frame rate. `setInterval` is not going to make a slow machine faster, though.